# SafeModeException : Name node is in safe mode

Tags: hadoop

I tried copying files from my local disk to `hdfs` . At first it gave `SafeModeException`. While searching for solution I read that the problem does not appear if one executes same command again. So I tried again and it didn't gave exception.

```
hduser@saket:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg/ /user/hduser/gutenberg
copyFromLocal: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.SafeModeException: Cannot create directory /user/hduser/gutenberg. Name node is in safe mode.
hduser@saket:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/gutenberg/ /user/hduser/gutenberg
```

Why is this happening?. Should I keep safemode off by using this code?

```
hadoop dfs -safemode leave
```

Comment: What was the time difference between executing the commands? It takes a few moments for all the data nodes to come online when you first start up HDFS services.

Comment: FYI, the command to leave safemode in my version of hadoop is: `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`.

Comment: @saket did you find solution to your problem??

Comment: [Check this](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-how-to-leave.html)

Comment: the correct command to leave safe mode is `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Answer (score 18):

*NameNode* is in **safemode** until configured percent of blocks reported to be online by the data nodes. It can be configured by parameter `dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct` in the `hdfs-site.xml`

For small / development clusters, where you have very few blocks - it makes sense to make this parameter lower then its default `0.9999f` value. Otherwise 1 missing block can lead to system to hang in safemode.

Comment: While cluster in the safe mode you can read from HDFS, but you cannot write to HDFS.

Answer (score 15):

Go to the `hadoop` path into `bin`(in my system `/usr/local/hadoop/bin/`),

```
cd /usr/local/hadoop/bin/
```

Check there is a file `hadoop`,

```
hadoopuser@arul-PC:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ ls
```

the o/p will be,

```
hadoop            hadoop-daemons.sh  start-all.sh       start-jobhistoryserver.sh  stop-balancer.sh          stop-mapred.sh
hadoop-config.sh  rcc                start-balancer.sh  start-mapred.sh            stop-dfs.sh               task-controller
hadoop-daemon.sh  slaves.sh          start-dfs.sh       stop-all.sh                stop-jobhistoryserver.sh
```

Then you have to off safe mode by using command `./hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave`,

```
hadoopuser@arul-PC:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ ./hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

you will get response as,

```
Safe mode is OFF
```

Note: I created Hadoop user with the name of `hadoopuser`.