# HDFS Safe mode issue

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-pig

I am facing an issue with HDFS. Error is given below:

> Problem accessing /nn_browsedfscontent.jsp. Reason:
>
> Cannot issue delegation token. Name node is in safe mode.The reported
>   blocks 428 needs additional 2 blocks to reach the threshold 0.9990 of
>   total blocks 430. Safe mode will be turned off automatically.

I even tried to leave safe mode using the command. But I am getting superuser privilege issue, even if I tried as the root user. I am using CDH 4.

Can any one let me know why this is happening and how to over come from this?

Answer (score 1):

```
hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

After doing the above command, Run hadoop fsck so that any inconsistencies crept in the hdfs might be sorted out.

Use  hdfs  command instead of  hadoop command for newer distributions:

[hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-how-to-leave.html)

Answer (score 0):

Modify `dfs.safemode.threshold.pct` proprty in `hdfs-site.xml` and restart the service.

For more details refer: [SafeModeException : Name node is in safe mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729510/safemodeexception-name-node-is-in-safe-mode)