# Name Node is in safe mode. Cannot be resolved

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Hi when I tried to put a file in hdfs I am getting an error which says Name Node is in safe mode. I excecuted the command ./bin/hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave  and I got the message Safe mode is OFF. But the problem remains the same while putting a file in hdfs. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: Make sure that at least 1 active datanode running.......

Comment: data node is running  @127.0.0.1:50010 .

Comment: Ensure all nodes are running... Checked logs?

Comment: Provide more details about your cluster configuration, how many nodes you have

Comment: I am running on a single system. I am very new to hadoop system. Where I can find the log files?

Comment: See this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729510/safemodeexception-name-node-is-in-safe-mode

Comment: I already read that link Mr. Gaurav Dave. From there I got the command to quit from safemode. But I didn't understand how to configure in hdfs_site.xml

Comment: thank you all for the help. May be because of the time span required to start the data node. Now its working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

A month ago, I encounter the same question with you. And I solve it with the help of log. My question is disk capacity is not enough to use. So, in your problem , Please check your logs and find what you want, you can get some useful information from logs.

Like this:

/root/ec-perf-test/hadoop/logs

hadoop-root-namenode-node10.log

If you also have any question with your problem after you have already check your logs. Please feel free to contact with me.